# Ruby on Rails methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I an looking to delve a little deeper into Ruby On Rails and am interested in seeking more knowledge when it comes to methods. I am aware of the rails api documentation, but not being familiar with a lot of the terminology or where the specific methods can be used it is to big to be useful at this stage (hope that makes sense).

What I was looking for is any particular methods I should pay attention too, more like most commonly used, just so I can practice with them for now, then once I have grasped a better understanding then i can look at more.

Any resources or documentation that has helped anyone, please feel free to let me know

Thanks in advance

Comment: Start here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ and here http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=3.2

Comment: If you have a strong knowledge about the metaprogramming then you can always access and study the code of Rails on the GitHub..but before that I would recommand that you go through all the topics that are given in the Rails Guide...

Answer (score 1):

Some resources maybe help you:

- [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)
- [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) and about [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)
- Some videos [Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/)
- Read book [Rails 3 way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601661)
- [Objects On Rails](http://objectsonrails.com/#sec-12_1)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, you should probably be asking this question on Reddit or in the RoR talk group.. the reason being is that there is likely no single correct answer. Check this page out:

http://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/ys318/what_to_read_after_hartls_rails_tutorial/

As the title in the URI suggests, you should definitely start with Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.

Also see:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!forum/rubyonrails-talk